# Photoshop shortcuts only work sporadically

Tags: macos, keyboard, adobe-photoshop

Using `CMD+J` on a layer to duplicate it works... sometimes. But not always.

Using `CMD+Ctrl+D` (my own binding) to delete a layer works... sometimes. But not always.

I'm unable to grasp why it only works sometimes. I noticed switching tools sometimes makes it work but that doesn't always help.

Anyone experience anything similar?

I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard, Photoshop CS5 12.0.2 (English), a few custom shortcut binding but not many.

Answer (score 1):

One of my peeves about InDesign is that the document navigation shortcut keys (e.g. alt+spacebar) are tool/context dependent instead of globally available. Perhaps you are experiencing the same issue here. Also, some Photoshop activity requires you to commit or cancel the change (such as using the transform gadgets). While in this state, certain actions are not possible.

Comment: Yes, some of the UI widgets (layer opacity for instance) prevent hotkeys from firing if they have focus.

Answer (score 0):

on a windows machine you can toggle between language settings with SHIFT + ALT.
I think on a mac it is either the same or CMD + SHIFT

Try that and see if you shortcuts work again.
I think this is the solution.

If this shortcut is incorrect i think you can find it here: System Preferences > International > Input Menu > Input menu shortcuts